# Why acquiring lock in Ecto tests doesn't work?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Given this Ecto test:

```
test "fails to acquire lock" do
  %{rows: [[lock_acquired]]} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock($1)", [1337], [])
  assert lock_acquired

  %{rows: [[lock_acquired]]} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_xact_lock($1)", [1337], [])
  refute lock_acquired
end
```

It doesn't work. The 2nd line which tries to `pg_try_advisory_xact_lock` also manages to do so.

I actually tried to do:

```
test "fails to acquire lock" do
  parent = self()
  t = Task.async(fn ->
    Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.allow(Repo, parent, self())
    Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(ChargingIo.Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock($1)", [1337], [])
    :timer.sleep(1_000)
  end)

  :timer.sleep(100)
  %{rows: [[lock_acquired]]} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_xact_lock($1)", [1337], [])
  Task.await(t)
  refute lock_acquired
end
```

With the idea to test if locking from another process manages to prevent locking from current one.

Funny thing is, all this works as expected in dev console.

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Change the SQL Sandbox to be in shared mode and don't run this test asynchronously: `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Repo, {:shared, self()})`

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work. Maybe I used it wrong though. Found another solution in the mean time. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found a solution.

```
setup do
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Repo, :auto)
end

test "fails gracefuly when already locked" do
  t = Task.async(fn ->
    %{rows: [[lock_acquired]]} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock($1)", [1337], []) |> IO.inspect
    assert lock_acquired
    :timer.sleep(1_000)
  end)

  :timer.sleep(100)
  %{rows: [[lock_acquired]]} = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Repo, "SELECT pg_try_advisory_xact_lock($1)", [1337], []) |> IO.inspect
  refute lock_acquired

  Task.await(t)
end
```

So it seems I needed the `:auto` in setup, as explained in https://medium.com/@qertoip/making-sense-of-ecto-2-sql-sandbox-and-connection-ownership-modes-b45c5337c6b7.